# When can I remove 301 error?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

I recently change a domain name of one of my site.

This is how I did it.

1. Buy new hosting with new domain name.
2. Move that content and database to new hosting
3. Do 301 redirection to new domain

My old hosting account will be expired just after 4 months. Should I renew it just for these redirection part? I mean, we need to use these 301 redirection lifetime? Or can we just remove it after a few months?

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

1. Do you just want the new domain to be indexed within the search results
   instead of the old domain?
2. Or do you have important backlinks to the
   old domain which you want to redirect to the new domain?

**If first case**: Wait until the search results are updated with the new domain.

**Second case**: Either you change the target URLs from your important backlinks on the referring sites or you will lose the backlinks after the expiration of your hosting contract.